# How to get related Entities with azure mobile app Tablecontroller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

Hello I am tryin to get related entities using a table controller.

This is my member class which has a collection of subscriptions

```
public class Member : EntityData
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }


    }
```

This is the related entity is Subscription

```
public class Subscription : EntityData
    {
        public string MemberId { get; set; }
        public string ShopItemId { get; set; }
        public Member Member { get; set; }
        public ShopItem ShopItem { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I modify this

```
public class MemberController : TableController<Member>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            ScoreContraceptionContext context = new ScoreContraceptionContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Member>(context, Request);
        }

        // GET tables/Member
        public IQueryable<Member> GetAllMember()
        {
            return Query(); 
        }

        // GET tables/Member/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<Member> GetMember(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/Member/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<Member> PatchMember(string id, Delta<Member> patch)
        {
             return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/Member
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMember(Member item)
        {
            Member current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/Member/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteMember(string id)
        {
             return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
    }
```

to search for additional properties of the member class?

get tables/member currently returns

```
[{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.447Z","createdAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.447Z","version":"AAAAAAAACA4=","id":"DemoUser1","address":"Some place","lastName":"Doe","firstName":"John"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.448Z","createdAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.448Z","version":"AAAAAAAACBA=","id":"DemoUser2","address":"Some other place","lastName":"Foster","firstName":"Jane"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.448Z","createdAt":"2016-12-02T17:17:06.448Z","version":"AAAAAAAACBI=","id":"DemoUser3","address":"#1 Galgamar st, Gibralter","lastName":"Shamlah","firstName":"Quarin"}]
```

I would like the result to also include the subscriptions that the user has.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile app table relationship is much more complex than Asp.Net. The Azure Mobile Apps Client SDK doesn’t support $expand at currently, we need to do something on the server. Based on your description, you want to do one to many relationship. For this scenario, I would suggest you try [this article](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-26-relationship-advice/).